# Remove Old Operating System from Boot List

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, mbr, secure-boot

I was trying several Linux Distros. I finally decided to install one and completely wiped the disk that had the linux distros on it.

Now in Bios the boot Manager tells me of an old distro no longer installed. How to remove this distro from boot list? I think this is part of the MBR?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Ubuntu.  Are you using Ubuntu or another distribution after your 'tests'?

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using Ubuntu I installed on top of another distro

Comment: However, it is sort of irrelevant because at one time on another computer. I have three different boot options for ubuntu becauseI reinstalled it three times

Comment: Try running `sudo update-grub`.  If that works I'll put it in an answer, but basically you just have to 'refresh' the grub bootloader that Ubuntu uses, which will rescan for operating systems.  It should only find the ones that are actually isntalled.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thanks for your suggestion but that unfortunately didn't work. If you have any other suggestions please let me know.

Comment: I just found the answer in this video, it involves using bcdedit in cmd. Thanks.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=255ltqk7xDM